# Using vite plugins with Storybook and SvelteKit

Tags: storybook, vite, sveltekit

I have successfully set up `@poppanator/sveltekit-svg` with SvelteKit using the following configuration (`svelte.config.js`):

```
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import svg from '@poppanator/sveltekit-svg';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte',
        vite: {
            plugins: [svg()]
        }
    }
};

export default config;
```

This works when running the SvelteKit project using `npm run dev`. However, I cannot get the svg plugin to work inside Storybook.

I have the following Storybook configuration (`.storybook/main.cjs`):

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx|svelte)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-svelte-csf"
  ],
  "core": {
    "builder": "storybook-builder-vite"
  },
  "svelteOptions": { 
    preprocess: import("../svelte.config.js").preprocess 
  }
}
```

When importing SVG files in Storybook stories (or in components used by the stories), only the file path of the SVG file is returned. When importing SVG files inside a SvelteKit route, a Svelte component is returned as it should be.

I have tried this with Storybook 6.3.10 and 6.4.0-beta.7 with `storybook-builder-vite` (0.1.0).

How should this go together to make SVG imports work inside Storybook?

Comment: The `import()` is async, so a promise is being provided to `preprocess`, which might not be valid.  You could try duplicating your `svelte.config.js` config directly into main.js to see if that makes a difference.  And be sure to upgrade the vite builder using `npm sb@next automigrate`.

Answer (score 0):

While SvelteKit uses **Vite**, Storybook uses **Webpack**.

To get svg imports working you'll need to find a loader for webpack that behaves similar to the [@poppanator/sveltekit-svg](https://github.com/poppa/sveltekit-svg) plugin and [add that to your storybook configuration](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config).

I'm not sure similar loader exists (yet), depending on your usage, renaming the .svg files to .svelte could be an alternative

Comment: The OP is using `storybook-builder-vite` (which has now been renamed to `@storybook/builder-vite`, which swaps in vite instead of webpack for building your stories.